# Is there a memory-efficient way to explore solutions which are generated from permutations of the input?

Tags: c++, combinatorics

EDIT I may have solved this myself, please comment on my answer below.

I have a `std::vector<Problem> problems` and I need to generate a corresponding `std::vector<Solution> solutions`.

I have the algorithm which can generate a candidate `Solution` for a given `Problem` but the caveat is that the *order* I attempt to generate these affects whether the whole set can be solved.

```
// This function exists already. Solution::ok() tells us whether it worked.
Solution solve (
    const Problem &,
    const std::vector<Solution> & solutions_so_far);
```

Not only will the existence of a `Solution` change depending on what's already been solved, but the nature of the solution changes, so I can't cache any results.

I need an algorithm which will explore all permutations of `problems`, backtracking as necessary and returning immediately whenever the full set of solutions is found.

**We require that `solutions[i]` corresponds to `problems[i]`** but otherwise the particular order of the output doesn't matter. Note that `solutions_so_far`, above, implies that `problems` may already have been shuffled.

Here is the interface which I need to implement

```
// Returns a corresponding list, or an empty list if no complete solution found
std::vector<Solution> solve (
    std::vector<Problem>::iterator begin,
    std::vector<Problem>::iterator end)
{
    // ???
}
```

Now I'm stuck. How do I do this?

Also, can I do it in-place? i.e. reordering `problems` with std::move is okay but ideally **I don't want to allocate anything on the heap** for this. I imagine the function could shuffle the input before it recurses but I can't make this vague idea concrete, or convince myself that I'm completely covering the search space without repeating any work.

Comment: Your constraints seem overly strict to me. You've already allocated stuff in the heap, via the various vectors. And since enumerating all permutations is costy for very modestly sized sets and intractible for even slightly larger sets, I assume you're dealing with a rather small set and spend a lot of time on trying permutations, likely making a one-time allocation a non-issue. That's not to say you have to allocate any more, but perhaps it wouldn't be a problem if you did.

Comment: I won't need to hit every permutation an there's good reason to think it's tractable in my case. I can always add a parameter which counts the number of attempts and aborts after some limit. But I need to at least *start* systematically.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your algorihm on the problem set, referenced by indexes, so no copies wil be made, just index permutation:

```
std::vector<Solution> solve(std::vector<Problem>::iterator begin,
                std::vector<Problem>::iterator end)
{
    // Create a solution 
    std::vector<Solution> ret(std::distance(begin, end));
    // Define the search space 
    std::vector<int> indices(std::distance(begin, end)); // problem space
    std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);        // fill with the indices

    do
    { // The mapping "solution-problem" can be done through the permutation state
        int i(0);
        for (auto it(indices.begin()), ite(indices.end()); it != ite; ++it)
        {
            ret[i] = solve(*(begin+(*it)), ret); // solve should acept ret range
            if (ret[i++].ok())
            {
                if (it + 1 == ite) return ret; // all solved !
            }
            else break; // try another permutation
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(indices.begin(), indices.end()));


    return std::vector<Solution>(); // empty list
}
```

The indices vector is mandatory because std::next_permutation requires a "<" operator defined for (in this case) the Problem class (or a comp function) and no mention of such functions is made (in MSVC you get " error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Problem' (or there is no acceptable conversion) ")

Comment: As `Problems` can be moved, you can get rid of `indices` (need to sort problem thought).

Answer (score 0):

The book [combinatorial generation](http://www.1stworks.com/ref/RuskeyCombGen.pdf) has a function which maps a lexicographic listing of permutations to integers on page 66.  For example:

```
F4(0) = [1,2,3,4]
F4(1) = [1,2,4,3]
```

All you need on top of that is an iterator that takes in a permutation (represented as an array of indices) and iterates through your two lists in that order.  This would require you to allocation one array of size N (where N is the length of your input vectors) on the heap.

I would warn you though that once you get past 8 or so items you simply cannot iterate through all permutations (there are just too many).

If you absolutely could not allocate any memory then you could get away with reordering your input list but that would increase the complexity of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Perhaps someone can tell at a glance?

First, the single case solver.

```
typedef std :: vector <Problem> P;
typedef std :: vector <Solution> S;

bool solve (
    P :: iterator problem,
    S :: iterator so_far_start,
    S :: iterator so_far_end,
    Solution * output)
{
    if (/* can find s consistent with [so_far_start...so_far_end)*/)
    {
        *output = s;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Extending this to an ordered list.

```
bool solve_naive (
    P :: iterator begin,
    P :: iterator end,
    S :: iterator out_begin,
    S :: iterator out_end)
{
    auto in = begin;
    auto out = end;

    while (in < end)
    {
        if (! solve (in, out_begin, out, &*out))
            return false;

        ++in;
        ++out;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now the clever bit.

```
// reordering problems [at...end) as needed,
// write out corresponding solutions [out_at...out_end)
// consistent with [out_begin...out_at)
bool solve_permutations (
    P :: iterator at,
    P :: iterator end,
    S :: iterator out_begin,
    S :: iterator out_at,
    S :: iterator out_end,
    unsigned * limit)
{
    if (end == at)
        return true;

    if (0 == -- *limit)
        return false;

    if (solve_naive (at, end, out_at, out_end))
        return true;

    // try each other input in first position, let
    // recursion solve for some ordering of the remainder
    for (auto in = at + 1; in < end; ++in)
    {
        std :: swap (*in, *at);

        // this one must be solvable in first position
        if (! route (at, out_begin, out_at, &*out_at))
             continue;

        // all the rest must be solvable in any position
        if (solve_permutations (
            at + 1,
            end,
            out_begin,
            out_at + 1,
            out_end,
            limit))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Bringing it all together.

```
S solve_hopefully (P :: iterator begin, P :: iterator end)
{
    S solutions (end - begin, {});

    if (end - begin < WIDTH_LIMIT)
    {
        unsigned limit = DEPTH_LIMIT;

        // Will help if this high-level function
        // is called repeatedly.
        std :: random_shuffle (begin, end);

        return solve_permutations (
            begin,
            end,
            solutions .begin (),
            solutions .begin (),
            solutions .end (),
            & limit)
        ? solutions : S ();
    }
    else for (unsigned i = 0; i < SHUFFLE_LIMIT; ++i)
    {
        std :: random_shuffle (begin, end);

        if (solve_naive (begin, end, solutions .begin (), solutions .end ())
            return solutions;
    }

    return {};
}
```

This look okay to you guys?